# C# Array C with a formula

Tags: c#, arrays, formula

im new to programming and I am stuck on a part of a question.
After i create two methods-one for inputing Array and one for summing the elements that are odd and can be dividible to 5.I have to do this to three arrays-A,B and C.I've done all of this,but this time i have to find the elements of C(again),but with this formula:

```
((An-Bn)(A1-B1),(An-1 - Bn-1)(A2-B2),....(A1-B1)(An-Bn))
```

or in other words:

```
((A[n]-B[n])(A[0]-B[0]),(A[n-1]-B[n-1])(A[2]-B[2]),....,(A[1]-B[1])(A[n]-B[n])
```

If someone can help me to figure this out.I've tried a couple of things and most of them give the "Index out of bounds".
Thank you in advance.

```
namespace MethodsArrays
{

    class Program
    {
        //Tochka 1 a/ i b/
        static void Array(int[] p)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
            {
                p[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        static void Output(int [] p)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write(p[i] + "");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }        
        }
        static int Multiple(int[] p)
        {
            int br = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
            {
                if (p[i] % 2 == 1 && p[i] % 5 == 0)
                {
                    //for (int j = 0; j < p.Length;j++)
                    //{   
                        br += p[i];
                    //}
                }
            }
            return br;

        }
        //Tochka 2
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type the legth of the array.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("n= "+ n);
            Console.WriteLine();

            int[] a = new int[n];
            Array(a);
            Console.Write("Array A: "); 
            Output(a);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Length of B =  "+ n);
            Console.WriteLine();

            int[] b = new int[n];
            Array(b);
            Console.Write("Array B: ");
            Output(b);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Length of C= " + n);
            Console.WriteLine();
            int[] c = new int[n]; 
            Array(c); 
            Console.Write("Array C: "); 
            Output(c);
            Console.WriteLine();

            int br1 = Multiple(a); Console.WriteLine("br1=" + br1);
            int br2 = Multiple(b); Console.WriteLine("br2=" + br2);
            int br3 = Multiple(c); Console.WriteLine("br3=" + br3);

            double srgeo = (br1 * br2 * br3);
            double srg = Math.Pow(srgeo, (double)1 / 3);
            Console.WriteLine("Srednogeometrichno= "+ srg);
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: In which line does the error happen?

Comment: IndexOutOfBounds means you're acessing an index that is not set for that array.

Answer (score 0):

There there are `n` elements in `a` and `b` then the `i`-th element of `c` is

```
c[i] = (a[n-i-1]-b[n-i-1])*(a[i]-b[i])
```

Or more specifically, try the method below for composing `c`

```
    static int[] ComposeArray(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        if (a.Length == b.Length)
        {
            int n = a.Length;
            int[] c = new int[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                c[i] = (a[n-i-1]-b[n-i-1])*(a[i]-b[i]);
            }
            return c;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
```

since no test data was given in the question, I made up some on my own:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select((i) => i).ToArray();
        // [1,2,3,4,5]
        var b = Enumerable.Range(4, 5).Select((i) => i).ToArray();
        // [4,5,6,7,8]

        var c = ComposeArray(a, b);
        // [9,9,9,9,9]
    }
```

Comment: I've tried it and it worked,i was wondering if i had to use a for loop,but wasn't sure how to make this one.Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: You can do the same with LINQ and two `.Zip()` statements and a `.Reverse()` statement but its messy. Much cleaner with a for loop.